# Astah - How to clone a model with modify the previous one?

Tags: model, uml, clone, astah

I'm using Astah to create some UML models, when I clone a model the change on the new model is maked even on the model from which I cloned. How can I do to clone a model without change even the base model?

I tried to reset all model ID but it doesn't work.

Comment: Knowing Astah merely just by name, but how about making a file copy?

Comment: Yeah, I'm tryng to do this...

Answer (score 0):

using [Clone] menu in the structure tree should enable you to do what you want to do.

[image: Clone in Astah]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).